# sys.excepthook in multiprocessing.Process ignored?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, multiprocessing

Suppose we have the two files namely `mymanger.py` and `mysub.py`.

`mymanager.py`

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process

import mysub  # the process file


def main():

    xprocess = Process(
        target=mysub.main,
        )

    xprocess.start()
    xprocess.join()

    time.sleep(1)
    print(f"== Done, errorcode is {xprocess.exitcode} ==")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

`mysub.py`

```
import sys


def myexception(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
    print("I want this to be printed!")
    print("Uncaught exception", exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)


def main():
    sys.excepthook = myexception  # !!!
    raise ValueError()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit()
```

When executing `mymanager.py` the resulting output is:

```
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python\3.9\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "c:\program files\python\3.9\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lx\mysub.py", line 11, in main
    raise ValueError()
ValueError
== Done, errorcode is 1 ==
```

When the output i expected would be something like:

```
I want this to be printed!
Uncaught exception <class 'ValueError'>  <traceback object at 0x0000027B6F952780>
```

which is what i get if i execute `main` from `mysub.py` without the `multiprocessing.Process`.

I've checked the underlying cpython ([reference](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/multiprocessing/process.py#L290)) and the problem seems to be that the `try-except` in the `_boostrap` function takes precedence over my child processes `sys.excepthook` but from my understanding, shouldn't the excepthook from the childs process fire first and then trigger the `except` from the `_boostrap`?

I need the child process to handle the exception using the `sys.excepthook` function.
How can i achieve that?

Comment: Replace `multiprocessing.Process` with `threading.Thread` and I see both outputs. Interesting.

Comment: interesting indeed, sadly i'm bound to using `multiprocessing.Process`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sys.excepthook` is invoked when an exception goes uncaught (bubbling all the way out of the running program). But `Process` objects run their target function in a special bootstrap function (`BaseProcess._bootstrap` if it matters to you) that intentionally catches all exceptions, prints information about the failing process plus the traceback, then returns an exit code to the caller (a launcher that varies by start method).

When using the `fork` start method, the caller of `_bootstrap` then exits the worker with `os._exit(code)` (a "hard exit" command which bypasses the normal exception handling system, though since your exception was already caught and handled this hardly matters). When using `'spawn'`, it uses plain `sys.exit` over `os._exit`, but AFAICT the `SystemExit` exception that `sys.exit` is implemented in terms of is special cased in the interpreter so it doesn't pass through `sys.excepthook` when uncaught (presumably because it being implemented via exceptions is considered an implementation detail; when you *ask* to exit the program it's not the same as dying with an unexpected exception).

Summarizing: **No matter the start method, there is no possible way for an exception raised by your code to be "unhandled" (for the purposes of reaching `sys.excepthook`), because `multiprocessing` handles *all* exceptions your function can throw on its own**. It's *theoretically* possible to have an `excepthook` you set in the worker execute for exceptions raised *after* your `target` completes if the `multiprocessing` wrapper code itself raises an exception, but only if you do pathological things like replace the definition of `os._exit` or `sys.exit` (and it would only report the horrible things that happened because you replaced them, your own exception was already swallowed by that point, so don't do that).

---

If you really want to do this, the closest you could get would be to explicitly catch exceptions and manually call your handler. A simple wrapper function would allow this for instance:

```
def handle_exceptions_with(excepthook, target, /, *args, **kwargs)
    try:
        target(*args, **kwargs)
    except:
        excepthook(*sys.exc_info())
        raise  # Or maybe convert to sys.exit(1) if you don't want multiprocessing to print it again
```

changing your `Process` launch to:

```
    xprocess = Process(
        target=handle_exceptions_with,
        args=(mysub.myexception, mysub.main)
    )
```

Or for one-off use, just be lazy and only rewrite `mysub.main` as:

```
def main():
    try:
        raise ValueError()
    except:
        myexception(*sys.exc_info())
        raise  # Or maybe convert to sys.exit(1) if you don't want multiprocessing to print it again
```

and leave everything else untouched. You could still set your handler in `sys.excepthook` and/or `threading.excepthook()` (to handle cases where a thread launched in the worker process might die with an unhandled exception), but it won't apply to the main thread of the worker process (or more precisely, there's no way for an exception to reach it).

Comment: thanks for taking the time for such a great writeup. The "solution" feels kinda hacky but i understand it can't be done any other way.